# How to Count Nested Child from single table Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, relationship

Relation method
User model:

```
   public function children()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(self::class, 'referrer_id')->with('children');
    }
```

Controller Method:

```
 $user = User::with('children')->where('id',$this->request->UserId)->get();
```

Response

```
{
    "status": true,
    "status_code": "Success",
    "message": true,
    "payload": {
        "profile": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "referrer_id": null,
                "name": "beciwerugy",
                "username": "lahaky",
                "email": "figo@mailinator.com",
               
                "children": [
                    {
                        "id": 3,
                        "referrer_id": 1,
                        "name": "asd",
                        "username": "asde",
                        "email": "asda@asd.com",
                      
                        "children": [
                            {
                                "id": 4,
                                "referrer_id": 3,
                                "name": "asd",
                                "username": "asde12",
                                "email": "as12a@asd.com",
                              
                               
                                        ]
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I want to count all nestedchild at once
Currently im getting all nested child in ther list
but i just want count

Comment: This structure can quickly turn  to a nightmare once you have  some data. expect timeouts once you hit 5th level deep on multiple children. The answer to your question is **you cant count them" in this structure, you will need to query the users till MaxLevel -1 and then count all the results. (even though MaxLevel is unknown and will end up running MaxLevel +1 to be sure there is no left over)

Comment: @N69S why we can't count them? I can count children but that is not easy way i just want if someone know through relationship or query !